# Why my mongo database was dropped by attacker?

Tags: mongodb

I already setup mongod with authentication but forget to expose port 27017 to public but I don't understand why attacker can drop my database?

*** Updated, issued has been resolved, I forgot to re-enable auth after change something on config files and attacker random scripting execute drop database command on server which not enable auth.

Server Information:
MongoDB Server 4.0.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the remote access to your MongoDB.
In mongo conf file, setting bind_ip you can restrict.

Refer this link : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/enabling-and-disabling-remote-access-to-a-mongodb-server/

In your case, it might be accessible to remote users using `mongoclient`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that they can access to my MongoDB because the port was published, but how can they bypass authentication to execute drop database command?